# Blender file import assimp

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, assimp

I want to import a blender file using Assimp (in c#), all classic format like .obj works.

I saw here that the better way to do it is to convert the blender file in one more usual, like obj.

> You need to open your file .blend and export it to .3ds, .obj etc.

[How do you load Blender files using Assimp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046553/how-do-you-load-blender-files-using-assimp)

But my question is how can I convert it, I searched in Assimp Documentation, there's nothing for convert and I can't import blender file so I can't export it in another kind.

I search for another library but I also find nothing.

Comment: Download blender, open the file and re-export to obj then load that using assimp?

Comment: Yes but I would like to get a way to "automate" this step for further uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Blender via command line, allowing it to run a python script, to open .blend, then export to another format, then run that through a custom assimp process you were trying to do.    Not sure your target format, but you could also just have blender go right to that instead of assimp.

This is something semi-similar, but you will need to connect the dots.
http://indygamedev.com/blender/automating-fbx-model-export-process/

Answer (score 0):

Use Blender 2.79 (not 8.x).

Pack all textures, then save the *.blend to your data directory.
Then unpack all images which will put them in "textures*.*".
Resave the file after the Unpack -
Assimp should now see your textures.